# Saving tags into a database table in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following setup for my CakePHP app:

```
Posts
id
title
content

Topics
id
title

Topic_Posts
id
topic_id
post_id
```

So basically I have a table of Topics (tags) that are all unique and have an id. And then they can be attached to post using the Topic_Posts join table. When a user creates a new post they will fill in the topics by typing them in to a textarea separated by a comma which will then save these into the Topics table if they do not already exist and then save the references into the Topic_posts table. I have the models set up like so:

Post model:

```
class Post extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'Post';

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Topic' => array('with' => 'TopicPost')
    );
}
```

Topic model:

```
class Topic extends AppModel
{
    public $hasMany = array(
        'TopicPost'
    );
}
```

TopicPost model:

```
class TopicPost extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Topic', 'Post'
    );
}
```

And for the New post method I have this so far:

```
public function add()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {
        //$this->Post->create();

        if ($this->Post->saveAll($this->request->data))
        {

            // Redirect the user to the newly created post (pass the slug for performance)
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'posts','action'=>'view','id'=>$this->Post->id));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Server broke!');
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I have used `saveAll` but how do I go about dealing with the Topic data?

I've seen things like: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dooltaz/2007/05/02/simple-tagging-behavior but I'm looking to do this a lot simpler and more modern (that article dates 2007) and I'm also using CakePHP 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would implement a method in Topic (Model) like this:

```
/**
 * This methods saves the topics coming from a post save and associates them with the right post.
 * 
 * @param string $postId The post id to save associations to.
 * @param string $topics A comma seperated list of topics to save.
 * @param bool Save of all topics succeeded (true) or not (false).
 */
    public function savePostTopics($postId, $topics){
        // Explode the topics by comma, so we have an array to run through
        $topics = explode(',', $topics);
        // Array for collecting all the data
        $collection = array();

        foreach($topics as $topic){
            // Trim it so remove unwanted white spaces in the beginning and the end.
            $topic = trim($topic);

            // Check if we already have a topic like this
            $controlFind = $this->find(
                'first',
                array(
                    'conditions' => array(
                        'title' => $topic
                    ),
                    'recursive' => -1
                )
            );

            // No record found
            if(!$controlFind){
                $this->create();
                if(
                    !$this->save(
                        array(
                            'title' => $topic
                        )
                    )
                ){
                    // If only one saving fails we stop the whole loop and method.
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    $temp = array(
                        'TopicPost' => array(
                            'topic_id' => $this->id,
                            'post_id' => $postId
                        )
                    )
                }
            }
            else{
                $temp = array(
                    'TopicPost' => array(
                        'topic_id' => $controlFind['Topic']['id'],
                        'post_id' => $postId
                    )
                )
            }
            $collection[] = $temp;
        }

        return $this->TopicPost->saveMany($collection, array('validate' => false));
    }
```

I did not tested it, but it should work.

You would call this AFTER saving the post itself giving it the post id and the topics from the data array. Make sure you handle the return of that method. If a topic saving fails is this a reason for deleting the whole post? Since there is no good implemented rollback api in cakephp yet you may have to delete the post from the database, if you want so. Or do you just give a succes message to the user who wrote the post and log the error?

By the way: Following the cakephp conventions the model and the table for association also have to be named **PostTopic** and **post_topic**. Alphabetically ;) You may want to change it in this early state of your project.

Greetings
func0der

Comment: Awesome that's worked fine. I haven't had to change any of my table names or Model names though? Thanks ;)

Comment: No you do not HAVE to change it. But by the cakephp conventions you should ;)
Read through this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm (The info box beneath the examples)